# C++ unwanted type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have the two following functions:

```
  template<class F, class... Args>
  auto runAt(F&& function, const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point& timePoint, Args&&... args)
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type> {
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;
    std::future<return_type> futureResult;

    auto packagedTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_type()> >
    (std::bind(std::forward<F>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    futureResult = packagedTask->get_future();

    this->addTask(Task([this, packagedTask]() {
        (*packagedTask)();
      }), timePoint);
    return futureResult;
  }

  void runAt(const Task& task,
             const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point& timePoint);
```

In my main.cpp file, I created a Task object, assigned a function to it and pushed it into my scheduler. runAt are scheduler's functions.

This is the code:

```
... // Task initialization
scheduler.runAt(task, std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
```

The problem is that the templated function is called instead of the one taking a Task as parameter. I understand that both functions are valid since the first parameter is templated and the variadic argument object is empty.

I have two questions:

1) How to call the second method (consider that the return types are not the same)

2) Not very important but I'm curious to know how this does not fail during the compilation

```
  auto packagedTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_type()> >
    (std::bind(std::forward<F>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

Comment: The two functions have different names: `runTaskAt` and `runAt`.

Comment: `runTask` and `runTaskAt` do not overload. Do they have the same name in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I just modified the names before writting the post, I edit my post

Comment: "Not very important but I'm curious to know how this does not fail during the compilation" which part do you expect to fail, and why?

Comment: The bind, since in my mind you can only bind functions

Comment: It can bind anything that's callable. Is `Task` not callable?

Comment: Yes it is, that explains why

Comment: You didn't show us the definition of `task` variable. I believe that if it's type differs from `const Task&` then compiler creates a specialization of the templated function which is a better match for the type of `task` (e.g. it doesn't need to convert from non-const& to const&).

Comment: Task task([&stop, &scheduler]() { std::cout << "message" << std::endl; });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) How to call the second method (consider that the return types are not the same)

Constrain the first one.

```
template<class F, class... Args,
         class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, Task>{}>>
auto runAt(F&& function, const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point& timePoint, 
           Args&&... args)
  -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type> {
  /* ... */
}
```

Incidentally,

```
auto packagedTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_type()> >
(std::bind(std::forward<F>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

is incorrect. `bind` does special handling for nested binds and placeholders, which you don't want, since you computed the return type as `typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I expected